# How can I set the LayoutParams of an View Programmatically?

Tags: android, view, parameters

You know this JoystickView from http://code.google.com/p/mobile-anarchy-widgets/wiki/JoystickView ?
Well, I tried to implement it. No Problems with it. I couldn't change It's size because I Added It programmatically. I somehow found out how to change the size, but now It's stuck in the upper left corner and everything I found for three hours got me a NullPointerException on the LayoutParams param I've created or was rejected because It wasn't castable or something to begin with.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements JoystickMovedListener{

private GraphicsHolder mGraphicsHolder;
private String TAG = "GameActivity";

/*
 * creates a new GraphicsHolder and sets it its ContentView
 * the GraphicsThread is being included in the GraphicsHolder
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "created");

    FrameLayout gameScreen = new FrameLayout(this);

    mGraphicsHolder = new GraphicsHolder(this);

    JoystickView Joystick = new JoystickView(this);


    // I need to set the Gravity HERE


    Joystick.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams(500,500));

    gameScreen.addView(mGraphicsHolder);
    gameScreen.addView(Joystick);

    setContentView(gameScreen);
}
}
```

Now Here's my Question: can you somehow set the Gravity of this View programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried adding the JoyStickView in XML instead?

Comment: I think Joystick extend View So try this way Joystick.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(500,500)); instead RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams()

Comment: @Karakuri Yes I did Before and somehow failed. But ... Thanks for the Idea I just got, I'll try that after school.

Comment: @HareshChhelana It looks the same way as before, but since it probably improves performance or something: Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer, but it's a completely different approach, since none of the above or those I found elsewhere worked for me.

I did the following changes in the onCreate method:

```
    mGraphicsHolder = new GraphicsHolder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    setContentView(mGraphicsHolder);

    getWindow().addContentView(inflate.inflate(
        R.layout.controllayout, null), new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    Joystick = (JoystickView) getWindow().findViewById(R.id.joystickView1);
    Joystick.setOnJostickMovedListener(this);
```

Now I got my Joystick on an XML Layout, but It actually works (at least in my case where nothing else worked), and it's quite easy to make changes in things of Layout etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500,500);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

Joystick.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set gravity center to FrameLayout and use ViewGroup.LayoutParams set Joystick LayoutParams :

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
gameScreen.setLayoutParams(params);

Joystick.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(500,500));
```

Comment: setting the params to gameScreen ... thats new, I'll try it :)

Comment: It didn't work, but I didn't got a NullPointer. It's still in in the upper Left corner when I set the Gravity to BOTTOM. But Thanks Anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) Joystick.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;// desired gravity

Joystick.setLayoutParams(params);
```

dont change ur code just add this after `setContentView(gameScreen);` hope it works

Comment: There is no Joystick.setGravity(int)! and when I tried the upper one before I got a NullPointer ;)

Comment: Okay Thanks I'll try it when I'm back home :)

Comment: Crash Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException for the line `params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;`.